# Is it common for pet allergies not to be aggrivated until after you've left the house?

Tags: cats, allergies

We've owned a cat for about 2 1/2 years now - the cat's fur has never aggravated my allergies before.  I do get aggravated allergy symptoms at work, but I have always attributed this to poor air quality (I am allergic both to pets and dust).

But recently, we took in a new cat with longer hair, and while my allergies have not been aggravated at home, they seem to be getting worse at work.

This could be because of an unseasonable drop in temperature kicking the heat system on instead of the cooling system, but I want to rule out pet dander first.

Is it possible that my pet's dander is causing my allergy symptoms to trigger several hours after I've left the house?

Comment: i think this is a little off topic here,it is a better fit over at our sister site health.se.